# Not sure how signal handler is being called

Tags: signals

Code:

```c
#include <signal.h>

static void sigHandler(int sig) {
    printf("Ouch!\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int j;

    if (signal(SIGINT, sigHandler) == SIG_ERR)
        perror("signal");

    for (j = 0; ; j++) {
        printf("%d\n", j);
        sleep(3);
    }
}
```

I am not sure how the code works. sigHandler clearly takes in one argument that is an integer. However, in the if statement we write `(signal(SIGINT, sigHandler) == SIG_ERR)`. Clearly when we call sigHandler, we are NOT passing in an integer value so why doesn't the program tell us it's an error? Why does the program still work as intended? Also I am not sure how the "signal" function works either.

According to the Kerris textbook on linux the syntax for signal functions is as follows `void ( *signal(int sig, void (*handler)(int)) ) (int);` We can clearly see that the handler function in the syntax is a pointer but in the actual code, we are NOT using a pointer to a function. Why is that?

Answer (score 3):

> Clearly when we call sigHandler, we are NOT passing in an integer value so why doesn't the program tell us it's an error? Why does the program still work as intended? Also I am not sure how the "signal" function works either.

Surely, "we" don't call the signal handler—the system does upon receipt of the signal.  The `signal()` system call just installs the handler: "signal() sets the disposition of the signal signum to handler, which is either SIG_IGN,  SIG_DFL,  or the address of a programmer-defined function (a "signal handler")." There you go.

Btw. to quote once again from the manual page: "The behavior of signal() varies across UNIX versions, and has also varied historically across different versions of Linux.  Avoid its use: use sigaction(2) instead."

> We can clearly see that the handler function in the syntax is a pointer but in the actual code, we are NOT using a pointer to a function. Why is that?

The compiler makes the necessary cast automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You need to brush up on C...

> However, in the if statement we write (signal(SIGINT, sigHandler) == SIG_ERR). Clearly when we call sigHandler, we are NOT passing in an integer value

That statement doesn't call `sigHandler`. It calls `signal`. The parenthesis are a required part of the C function call syntax, so `sigHandler` there isn't a function call.

> ... the syntax for signal functions is as follows void ( *signal(int sig, void (*handler)(int)) ) (int); We can clearly see that the handler function in the syntax is a pointer but in the actual code, we are NOT using a pointer to a function. Why is that?

When you use a function name without the parenthesis, what you get is a pointer to that function. So that is using a function pointer.

Answer (score 0):

> Clearly when we call sigHandler, we are NOT passing in an integer value so why doesn't the program tell us it's an error?

That line doesn't *call* `sigHandler` at all; it passes it to `signal()` as the function pointer.  That might be clearer written this way:

```
if (signal(SIGINT, &sigHandler) == SIG_ERR)
```

Notice the "address of" operator, `&`.  However, in this case it is actually optional -- just the name of the function will serve as a function pointer.

To explain a bit, the compiler checks that the signature of the function pointed to matches the parameter to `signal()`.  If this passes, at runtime the system can call it with an `int` argument as required.  The `signal()` function is just a means of telling the system about the handler.

Answer (score 0):

Signal handler types are fairly tricky. I think it works like this: when the compiler encounters this line:

```
static void sigHandler(int sig) {
```

It creates a symbol named "sigHandler". The type is `void (*)(int)`. Your example declaration of `signal()` (the system call that sets a signal handling function) has a prototype argument `void (*handler)(int)`. The "handler" token is just a dummy: you could put any valid C language identifier in for it, or nothing.

When the compiler gets to the actual invocation of `signal(SIGINT, sigHandler)` it checks to see if a symbol `sigHandler` of the proper type exists, and it does as you defined just such a symbol above the invocation of `signal()`. Sometime during linking (static and/or dynamic), the actual physical address of `sigHandler` gets into the code.

The actual mechanics of signal handling are also tricky.

Once the program starts running, the physical address of `sigHandler` gets passed as an argument to the system call `signal()`, along with the integer 2, which is the value of SIGINT manifest constant. That's where the function pointer exists - it's the physical address of `sigHandler()` at run-time. The Unix/Linux kernel will keep that address in some data structure associated with the process that matches the number SIGINT (2 by convention or standard) to that physical addres.

If and when a SIGINT arrives for your process, the Unix/Linux kernel arranges for your process to stop, and then does something like put together a stack frame for `sigHandler()` which contains a value 2 (SIGINT) for the `int sigint` formal argument of `sigHandler()`, change the stack pointer register to match the new stack frame, change the instruction pointer register to the physical address it stored when `signal()` got called. The next instruction executed is for `sigHandler()`.  Lots goes on under the covers of signal handling.